# create new dataframe grouped by one column and new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame( {
   'A': ['d','d','d','f','f','f','g','g','g','h','h','h'],
   'B': [5,5,6,7,5,6,6,7,7,6,7,7],
   'C': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
   'S': [2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2012,2013]     
    } );

df
```

I'd like to create a new dataframe, where column A is grouped and the sums of columns B and C are shown in new columns 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015 and 2016.

Comment: A B C S
0 d 5 1 2012
1 d 5 1 2013
2 d 6 1 2014
3 f 7 1 2015
4 f 5 1 2016
5 f 6 1 2012
6 g 6 1 2013
7 g 7 1 2014
8 g 7 1 2015
9 h 6 1 2016
10 h 7 1 2012
11 h 7 1 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.B + df.C).groupby([df.A, df.S]).sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
S  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016
A                              
d     6     6     7     0     0
f     7     0     0     8     6
g     0     7     8     8     0
h     8     8     0     0     7
```

---

```
df['D'] = df.B + df.C

df = df.groupby(['A','S'])['D'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
S  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016
A                              
d     6     6     7     0     0
f     7     0     0     8     6
g     0     7     8     8     0
h     8     8     0     0     7
```

Another solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df['D'] = df.B + df.C
df = df.pivot_table(index='A', columns='S', values = 'D', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
print (df)
S  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016
A                              
d     6     6     7     0     0
f     7     0     0     8     6
g     0     7     8     8     0
h     8     8     0     0     7
```

Comment: thanks jezrael, this works. I do however, have another question regarding the previous one. if I want to have the column fill out -1 when Result is not 'H', how do I amend the np.where function?

df3['profit'] = np.where(df3['Result'] == 'H', df3['column value H'],

Comment: what if want to only show the lines where all columns are > 0?

Comment: sorry, I was offline. I add answer to your newest question. Is it correct? If not, can you change sample?

Comment: Thank you, I edit answer. It is same as another, only difference is `|` (or) is changed to `&` and.

Comment: hi jezrael. what if I want to add in the count of values that have been summed in df = (df.B + df.C).groupby([df.A, df.S]).sum().unstack(fill_value=0),  per year?

Comment: I think the best is create new question. You use nice sample data, so I think your questions are very nice. Thank you.